# Send sound to different audio devices

Tags: c#, service, expression, media, encoder

Is it possible to play a sound on a playback device that is not set as default playback device?
I need to play multiple files simultaniously trough multiple output devices.

Does anyone knows a solution for .net? (C#)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you will have to go to lower level API. You can try find C# wrapper for Wasapi, ASIO, DirectSound or MediaFoundation. Maybe XNA framework could do the job, which is managed framework over directX

Answer (score 1):

well I was playing around with similar issue.

1. XNA could not do send output to specific device.
2. I have ended out with http://naudio.codeplex.com/, which is exactly what you need. It's C# wrapper for Wasapi, ASIO, DirectSound libraries. It also includes many very helpful classes for converting, decoding, visualizing etc. For simple player, check out NAudioDemo sample project.

find out CreateWaveOut() method. This is where you should select your playbackdevice.
for example:

```
MMDevice device = new MMDeviceEnumerator()
     .EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.All)
     .FirstOrDefault(d => d.ID == "yourplaybackdeviceid");
IWavePlayer waveOut = new WasapiOut(device, AudioClientShareMode.Shared, false, latency);
```

Download the naudio library from sourcecode tab not from Download->Release, it's not very actual and it's little buggy.

Answer (score 0):

another good tool is bass.net
http://www.un4seen.com/